# why event.target does not fire on the following code while simple click event handler works?

Tags: javascript, dom, event-listener

Following is the code

```js
(function(window){
  
  var form = document.getElementById('form_element'),
      form2 = document.getElementById('form_element2'),
      container = document.getElementById('container');
  
  window.addEventListener('mouseup', getAlert);
  
  function getAlert(event) {
    if(event.target === form) {
      alert('I clicked on a form');
    }
  }
  
  form2.addEventListener('click', function() {
    container.innerHTML = '<h1>I am however working</h1>';
  });
  
})(window);
```

```css
#container {
  height:400px;
  width:400px;
  background:red;
}

#form_element {
  display:inline-block;
}
```

```html
<form action="" id="form_element">
  <input type="text" placeholder="Enter here..."/>
</form>

<form action="" id="form_element2">
  <input type="text" placeholder="Enter here..."/>
</form>

<div id="container">
  <h2>Something goes here</h2>
</div>
```

Could you help me with this, with some explanation? Does this differ in jquery selector?

I am stuck with such small situations. Could you please help me work it out.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that the `target` when the `mouse goes up` is the `input element` and not the `form`

Here are some ways to solve your problem

1. Check if the `target` is the `input element`

   ```
   window.addEventListener("mouseUp", getAlert);
   function getAlert(event) {
       if (event.target === form.firstElementChild) {
           alert('I clicked on a form');
       }
   }
   ```
2. Add the `listener` to the `form` so that there is no need to check anything

   ```
   form.addEventListener("mouseUp", getAlert);
   function getAlert(event) {
       alert('I clicked on a form');
   }
   ```
3. Check if the `target` is the `form` OR if the `target` is an `element` of the `form`

   ```
   window.addEventListener("mouseUp", getAlert);
   function getAlert(event) {
       if (event.target === form || form.contains(event.target)) {
           alert('I clicked on a form');
       }
   }
   ```
4. Use `CSS` to add some `padding` to the `form` so you can have space to click the `form` without clicking the `input`

   ```
   #form_element {
       padding: 20px;
   }
   ```
5. Use `CSS` to make the `input element` "invisible" to the mouse

   ```
   #form_element>input {
       pointer-events: none;
   }
   ```

Comment: @jeff No problem, so which method do you choose?

Comment: I used the contain method nick. This helped with preventing closing a dropdown container once the child elements inside that DIV is clicked. Although, I have a question. How to select all the child elements inside a div properly. I think in native jquery $ sign select all child elements, in JS it returns an array. However, how to select all the child and subchild elements in JS.

Comment: @jeff Try this `document.querySelector("#form_element *")`, this should return an array with every child contained in `form_element`

Comment: Thanks for the feedback. Good day